# Is the Baum Framptom a valid alternative to Big Bang?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics

In the [Baum Frampton model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model#The_Baum.E2.80.93Frampton_model), proposed in 2007, because $\epsilon\lt-1$, after the [Big Rip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Rip) the universe starts again empty. The problem of this model is that inverting the arrow of the time, after a certain number of Big Rips it should have been a single universe from which all the sequence of Big Rips started. Is this model compatible with the astronomical observations of the last years and how is it possible to explain in the contest of this model the anomalies in the background microwave radiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if it is compatible with observations of 2013. However, I do remember that in one of Frampton's papers, he stated (back in mid 2000s) that the phantom energy density that he was considering was almost ruled out. It is unlikely that any of these models will be confirmed in our lifetime, and it is also unlikely that they will ever be confirmed, but I think that the cyclic model is too beautiful to give up on just yet.